# How to play video and audio together simultaneously with gstreamer in GTK3.0

Tags: c, audio, gtk3, gstreamer-1.0

I have a GUI that I played video on it. I use Gtk3.0 for GUI and I use gstreamer1.0 for play video. But when video play, I want  play audio. So, when playing video, I want give information audio message. Video should non stop play when play audio. I use gstreamer example code and I modified code according to myself. (example code is:https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/toolkit-integration.html)  I don't know how can I add second element(audio) on background. How should I added second element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this shape. No need to use `gst_init(&argc, &argv);`. Just add `pipeline` to your code. You can find this code gstreamer website. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html

```
 #include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```